# padding in background image aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="warning">
    <span>text text text</span>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.warning
{
    background:#F2EEBB url(Images/warning_triangle.gif) no-repeat right center; 
    border:solid 1px red;
    margin:5px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:18px;
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

The problem is that the background image that aligned to the right don't have padding between it and the border. How can I add a padding between the image and the border?
(I cannot add elements to the div!)

Comment: I don't know if you can see the image - if not, I am sorry, my firewall prevent it.

Comment: please see my answer i am lagging some where please let me know.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without any changes in html, and only a little change in css you can accomplish that .Try this css - I just change the position of the warning icon.

```
background:#F2EEBB url(Images/warning_triangle.gif) no-repeat 99.5% center;

<div class="warning">
    <span>text text text</span>
</div>


.warning
{
    background:#F2EEBB url(Images/warning_triangle.gif) no-repeat 99.5% center; 
    border:solid 1px red;
    margin:5px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:18px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The simplest - the better.

Comment: To be exact, fields should be more or less the same width, if you use this as a class on lots of different fields and you want predictable results. Shorter fields might need 98% or less.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the ":after"-psuedo class. That also makes your icon show up if a user prints the page. I made you an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3EndH/).

Comment: This is a much better way than using a background image.

Answer (score 3):

To make it consistent as 18px padding from the right side you can use calc.

```
background-position-x: calc(100% - 18px);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a distance from the right or bottom edges for background images.

The easiest way to achieve the desired effect would be to add that space in the image itself. So you'd add a few pixels of empty space to the right side of warning_triangle.gif. That way, when you position it to the right side of your div, the empty pixels will be aligned on the right edge while the visible triangle will appear a few pixels away from the edge.

EDIT:

Using the :after pseudo-element as Per suggests is a clever solution that I was not aware of. Just remember that :after is not supported by IE 7 and earlier. So if you need to support these older browsers, this may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut that image in photoshop as per how much space you want in your design

Answer (score 0):

Setup your css in this way

```
background-color: #F2EEBB;
background-image: url('http://confluence.jetbrains.net/download/attachments/33436/warningIcon.png');
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/3EndH/2/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
article {
    padding: 0px 152px;
    background: transparent url('img.png') no-repeat right 152px top;
}
```

Works for IE9 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Find below the code for ReactJS:

```
background: `url(${Background}) white no-repeat 97%`,
```

or

```
backgroundPositionX: '97%',
```